# Picassa Data Feed API

Tags: picasa

I know it's old hat (relatively) but I can't seem to get the API to return rows passed 1,000, though the results from a query of show open search total results well exceeding that number.

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/all?q=elephants&start-index=1&max-results=11&v=2&prettyprint=true&alt=json&strict=true&kind=photo
```

Am I mis-interpreting the return of:

```
"openSearch$totalResults": {"$t": 195717},
```

Combinations of start-index and max-result that exceed 1,001 return an error of "Too many results requested".

Comment: I am pretty sure this has nothing to do with google-app-engine, so I am editing the tags.

Comment: same issue here. Even if i request for photos from start-index as 1000 and max-results as 10 i am getting error as to many results requested.

Answer (score 1):

The API doesn't support returning more than 1000 results for a query. If you need more results, you will have to refine your search query.

Answer (score 0):

It returns same error if your start-index is past total number of results available.