# Picasa WEB API returns only 1000 of 2400 public albums?

Tags: api, picasa

I've tried querying the Picasa WEb Albums API for an account that for sure contains more than 2400 public albums, but only returns 1000 results.

I know I must use the parameters start-index and max-results in the query and cycle for every 1000 results, but this doesn't produce the desired list.

I've also found that the returned data contains a  of only 1000 albums despite the fact that I KNOW I have 2400.

Any ideas, please help?

UPDATE: [Found this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7605227/2501416), which says maximum results by API cannot exceed 1000. If it is correct can you suggest a workaround?

How am I supposed to get a list of ALL my albums?

Answer (score 2):

'startindex' and 'maxresults' listed below in connection to Youtube api should have analogs for the picasa/google+ (photos) aspect. Check the api details in order to get parm names so you can set them in your data calls.

[youtube example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters)

Comment: I've already mentioned that in my question, despite the fact I DO use these params, it only reports a totalResults:1000

Answer (score 1):

I am also running into this same issue. Except I am trying to list photos instead of albums. If you figured out a work around I would love to see it.